# How to make object with variable-based values in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I’m trying to do is keep a database of users in an object so I can assign values to each user, however I can’t find out a way to do it.

I’ve tried just doing `var data = {}` and then `` eval(`data.user_${user} = value`) `` but that only writes undefined. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you declared, and stored a value in, the `user` variable?

Comment: I’ve tried setting it to 0 if it doesn’t exist but that doesn’t seem to make a difference

Comment: what is `user`? an ID or an object? you can use the user's id as attribute name in `data` and store the object there: `data[user.id] = user`

Comment: @germaio thats actually a good idea using just user.id instead of user_${user.id}, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```html
data[`user_${user}`] = value
```